# Subscription and email issues Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, newsletter, order-email

Hi I am having issues with subscriptions and my site sending emails out. I'm pretty sure they are being caused by the same thing but I can't figure out what. Whenever a user tries to subscribe they get this message: "Something went wrong with the subscription."

Also, the site is not sending out any emails (Account Signup, Newsletter, Forgot Password Request, etc)

Mandrill is disabled. (Disabling this fixed one of my other sites but not this one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall MageMonkey and test it will probably clear up your issue. MageMonkey for Magento 2 was (and probably still is) preventing transactional emails from sending.